# Need help to understand the following number theory proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there exist infinitely many integers n such that $n, n + 1, n + 2$ are each the sum of the squares of two integers:

Solution: First solution: Let a be an even integer such that $a^2 + 1$ is not prime. (For example, choose a ≡ 2 (mod 5), so that $a^2 + 1$ is divisible by 5.) Then we can write $a^2 + 1$ as a difference of squares $x^2 − b^2$, by factoring $a^2 + 1$ as rs with $r ≥ s > 1$, and setting x = (r + s)/2, b = (r − s)/2. Finally, put n = $x^2 − 1$, so that $n = a^2 + b^2$, $n + 1 = x^2$, n + 2 = $x^2 + 1$

I got lost in the following part:

Then we can write $a^2 + 1$ as a difference of squares $x^2 − b^2$, by factoring $a^2 + 1$ as rs with $r ≥ s > 1$. What is rs?. Can someone expand this proof, so it looks clearer?

Comment: That's a somewhat weird proof $a^2 + 1$ *can* be prime by setting $s=1$ and $r=a^2 + 1$.  And we can either have $a^2 +1$ be odd or $a^2 + 1$ be divisible by $8$  we just need $a^2 +1 = r*s = (\frac {r+s}2 + [r-\frac{r+s}2])([\frac{r+s}2 - s]-\frac{r+s}2)$ so that $r$ and $s$ are both even or both odd.

Comment: This problem has already been addressed there. Do not ask repeated questions.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170494/infinitely-many-n-such-that-n-n1-n2-are-each-the-sum-of-two-perfect-squa

Answer (score 2):

If $a^2 +1$ is not prime, then it can be written as a product:

$$a^2 + 1 = rs,$$ where $r \geq s \gt 1$.

$r$ and $s$ are simply these factors here.

Comment: how can you expand this further by explaining  why we can do the next setting?

Comment: Well, I hope you agree that we *can* define $x$ in the way that you have written in your question, and also $b$. I will leave it to you to work out why $x$ and $b$ are integers (this is important; if they weren't integers then you'd be stuffed). You can then define the integer $n$ in the way in which you have written, giving you the desired trio $n, n+1, n+2$, completing the proof. It's an elegant proof - particularly because proofs like this are (in my purely undergraduate experience) often done by contradiction, and this isn't.

Comment: Maybe $x=\frac{r+s}{2}, b=\frac{r-s}{2}$ is the key here?

Comment: It's certainly a key part of the proof, although (without trying to sound condescending) I currently am not seeing what is difficult to understand about defining $x$ and $b$ like this.

Comment: There is another confusing part so $a \equiv 2 mod 5$, but if we choose a = 2 then $a^2+1$ is prime.

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho You need to show that you have infinitely many choices of $a$; just take $a\equiv2\pmod{5}$ with $a>2$.

Comment: That part is showing to you that there are infinite choices of even $a$ such that $a^2 + 1$ is not prime.

Comment: @MattS , if you don’t understand what’s confusing about it, then you might not be the best person to answer the question... I find I can help people much better when I “get” where they’re stuck.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs This is true. If I had initially thought that was the problem, I wouldn't have answered. The question as posed asked about $r$ and $s$, which was something I did think I understood.

Comment: Looking more closely at the proof, how is it clear that $x$ and $b$ are integers? Must $r$ and $s$ have the same parity?

Comment: I believe $r$ and $s$ must both be odd, as $a^2 +1$ is odd.

Comment: If $a^2 + 1$ is odd then $r$ and $s$ are both odd.  However the proof would work just as well if $r$ and $s$ are both even i.e.  $a^2 + 1$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: And the proof will also work if $s =1 $ and $r = a^2 + 1$.  So $a^2 +1$ *could be prime.  Letting $a^2 + 1 = 17$ you get $80 = 8^2 + 4^2$ and $81 = 9^2 + 0^2$ and $82 = 9^2 + 1^2$.

Comment: Ah. I didn’t see the part where $a$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions:

1. Pick some even $a$ such that $a^2+1$ is not a prime, for instance some $a\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.
   Fine, let us pick $a=22$;
2. Write $a^2+1$ as $r\cdot s$ with $r\geq s >1$.
   Fine, $22^2+1 = 97\cdot 5$;
3. Write $a^2+1$ as a difference of squares through the previous decomposition.
   Fine, $22^2+1 = (51+46)(51-46) = 51^2-46^2$.

This gives that $51^2-1$ is the sum of two squares, $22^2+46^2$, so $51^2-1,51^2$ and $51^2+1^2$ are three consecutive numbers belonging to $\square+\square$. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: sorry I am so slow. Why does your math process entail that $51^2 - 1$ is the sum of two squares?

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho: consider $$22^2+1 = 51^2-46^2$$ and add $46^2-1$ to both sides.

Comment: where are you using this 'setting x = (r + s)/2, b = (r − s)/2'?

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho: $51=\frac{97+5}{2},\;46=\frac{97-5}{2}$.

Comment: x = (r + s)/2, b = (r − s)/2.  . How do we know x and b  are integers?

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho: $a$ is even, hence $a^2+1$ is odd and both $r$ and $s$ are odd, so both $r-s$ and $r+s$ are even.

Comment: 7 is not even and $7 \equiv 2 mod 5$

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho: so? The instructions tell to consider some $a$ which is even and $\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.

Comment: got it. I wonder how the author of this proof was able to come up with this solution.

Comment: @ElChavoDelOcho: they idea "unrolled": if we manage to construct $N$ such that $N^2-1$ is the sum of two squares we are done, since $N^2-1,N^2,N^2+1$ provide a solution. On the other hand it is not difficult to find solutions to $N^2-1=A^2+B^2$, since it is equivalent to $A^2+1 = (N-B)(N+B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $a^2 + 1$ be odd and $a^2 + 1$ not be prime.  The proof glibly assumes such numbers are easy to find by pointing out any $2 + 5k$ will be such a number.

Since $a^2 + 1$ is not prime nor then $a^2 + 1 = r*s$ for some odd $r, s$ and $s \le r$.

Let $x$ be the midpoint between $s$ and $r$.  (In other words $\frac {r+s}2$).  This midpoint is an integer because $r$ and $s$ are both odd.

Let $b = x-s = r-s$.  This means $r = x+b$ and $s= x-b$.  That's not surprising as $x$ is the midpoint and $b$ is the distance each is from the midpoint.

Consider the three consecutive numbers $n = x^2 -1$, $n+1 = x^2$ and $n + 2 = ^2 + 1$.

Obviously $n+1 = x^2 + 0^2$ is the sum of two squares. And so $n+2=x^2 + 1^2$.

But $n$ is as well because:

$a^2 + b^2 = (a^2 + 1) + b^2 - 1$

$= r*s + b^2 -1= (x+b)(x-b) + b^2 - 1$

$= x^2 -b^2 + b^2 -1 = x^2 - 1 = n$

So $n$ is the sum of $a^2+ b^2$.