# Two times the sum of two squares is a sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, sums-of-squares

For all $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ there are $c,d\in\mathbb Z$ such that 
$2(a^2+b^2)=c^2+d^2$.

The conjecture is tested for $a^2+b^2<1,000,000$ but I have problems with proving it.

Comment: See also [Show that every power of 2
is sum of two squares.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100506/242)

Comment: If you look at the algorithm below, you would see that one can calculate the sum of two squares of an integer N by calculating first the sum of two squares of the integer 2N.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118459/sum-of-two-squares-of-an-integer-n-the-simplest-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment4356705_2118459

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127654/parametrization-of-solutions-of-diophantine-equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this:
$$2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$$

which is a special case of [Diophantus' identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$$

Comment: @Lehs A strong consequence of the general identity is that the set of sums of two squares is closed under multiplication: not only does it work for two times the sum of two squares, it also works for 5 times, 10 times, 13 times, etc.